# How do I pass an XML file as a parameter in a python method?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm writing a class in python to parse data from XML, I want to pass the XML file name as a parameter so that I can initialize the tree and root in the constructor. How do I go about doing that? Here is my code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class cParser:

def __init__(self, file):
  tree = ET.parse(self.file)
  root = tree.getroot()
def getFilename():
   filename = root.attrib['filename']
   print("Filename is: %s" %(filename))

c1 = cParser('pythonxml.xml')
c1.getFilename()
```

Comment: You seem to already pass the file name to `cParser`. This question in unclear.

Comment: ... and also your indentation is wrong. Can you correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix your `class` declaration first:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class cParser:
    def __init__(self, file):
      tree = ET.parse(file)  # no need for self here
      self.root = tree.getroot()  # needs self here 

    def getFilename(self):  # missed self in arg list
       filename = self.root.attrib['filename']  # use self.root from init
       print("Filename is: %s" % filename)

c1 = cParser('pythonxml.xml')  # not a pythonic name for a class though
c1.getFilename()  # and not a pythonic name for method
```

Comment: It's correct for me, there must have been a problem while copying my code over here

Comment: So what's the problem now?

Comment: When i try to run the code i get an AttributeError: file cParser has no file attribute

Comment: As I said, your class declaration is wrong. Use class declaration from my answer.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I'm still learning python so I apologize if my code was painful to go through...